# On OS X, how do I change my shell from fish back to bash?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, fish

I'm kinda preferring bash lately to fish, and I'm wondering if I can change it back. I tried this command: `chsh -s /bin/bash` but closing the terminal and reopening it does not restore it to bash, but it's still fish.

In fact, how do I remove fish?

Comment: Hmm, that should work. What does `grep $USER /etc/passwd | sed 's/.*://'` print?

Comment: Did you 'sudo' that command? Eg, sudo chsh -s /bin/bash

Comment: Or, you can use System Preferences Accounts with a control-click on user. Check this SuperUser link: http://superuser.com/questions/379725/how-do-i-change-a-users-default-shell-in-osx

Comment: User accounts aren't kept in `/etc/passwd` on OS X so grepping won't reveal anything.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Go to System Preferences, Users & Groups, click the lock to make changes, right click (or Control click) on your username, choose "Advanced Options" and you should have a field to change your shell. Change it there, reboot, and your new shell should take effect.

Comment: It may be helpful to specify right clicking on the current user image, and then continue with selecting Advanced Options.

Comment: @Pippin Updated to mention right/control clicking on your username.

Comment: @Gustav I haven't tried it, but I don't believe so. It should only affect what shell opens up when you use the Terminal, log in via SSH, etc. It shouldn't affect logging in via the GUI at all; so if you screw it up, you should be able to change it back. That said, I haven't tried it, so caveat emptor.

Comment: On 10.13.1 you need to click on the username on the left pane, not the image.

Comment: How do you go back to fish? :D

Answer (score 38):

Very easy:

- from FISH to BASH :
  In your Fish terminal, type `bash --login` to switch to Bash
- from BASH to FISH :
  In your Bash terminal, type `fish` to switch to Fish

Answer (score 4):

**Update 10.13.1:**

Right-click (ctrl+click) on the username in the left pane, not the image.

[image]