# FishShell stopped launching

Tags: bash, shell, fish, iterm

I was using commands like

```
set -x fish_user_paths $fish_user_paths 'somepath'
```

Than my shell simply stopped launching.

Sounds very noobish but I really don't know how to revert it..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to change initial shell on System Preferences:

[On OS X, how do I change my shell from fish back to bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386292/on-os-x-how-do-i-change-my-shell-from-fish-back-to-bash)